# MySQL data too long error

Tags: mysql

One of the column in my table was initially created as a varchar(1000). Now there is a need to increase the size of that column to hold around 5000 characters. I used the `alter` statement to increase the size of that column.

`DESC table_name` as well as `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` clearly indicates the new size of that column to be 5000 characters. However, interestingly when I try to insert any data exceeding 1000 characters `ERROR 1406 (22001) : Data too long for column` error shows up.

Out of desperation I changed the datatype to text, and still it's limited to 1000 characters. Any suggestion?

I created an other dummy table with a column size of varchar(5000) and that works just fine.

Engine used is InnoDB and Default Charset is UTF8.

Comment: show your table schema by `DESC table_name` here .

Comment: run this query and post results please: 'show full columns from table_name;'

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin : Isn't it supposed to be `alter table table_name modify column col_name varchar(newsize)`

Comment: It's very interesting coz this problem occurs only in my local sandbox. In the test and production servers, it seems to work fine. And all of them run on exactly the same environment. I  believe it could be a MySQL bug.

Comment: @kodi You are correct; alter was for defaults, I always get the alter specification mixed up.. `ALTER [COLUMN] col_name {SET DEFAULT literal | DROP DEFAULT}` 
  `CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
        [FIRST|AFTER col_name]`
  `MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
        [FIRST | AFTER col_name]`

Comment: What **exactly** is the value of your MySQL query right before executing it?

Comment: Value of my query!? The field in question was varchar(1000), attempting to be changed to varchar(5000). No error which running the alter statement. New size shows up in desc Table. The same query works on other servers. Will try and update to the latest version of MySQL today.

Comment: Error 1118(42000) is the error I get when I try to dump my prod DB to my local sandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had what appeared to be exactly the same problem.  I had a column that was VARCHAR(30), and I used ALTER TABLE `myTable` MODIFY COLUMN `myColumn` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, to double its size.  But I kept getting "Error Code: 1406 Data too long for column 'myColumn' at row 1" whenever I tried to insert a value that was > 30 characters.  It seemed, somehow, that mySQL had some "memory" of the previous column size, and was still enforcing it, even though INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS showed the column's character_maximum_length as the new value, 60.  I was convinced it was a mySQL bug.

I eventually discovered the actual problem was that this particular table had a trigger on it, whose purpose was to maintain an audit trail of changes, by populating a similarly-defined `myTableHistory` table.  I had forgotten to do an ALTER TABLE `myTableHistory` to increase the size of the same column in that table.

Comment: To check for the type of problem I had, the following can be useful: 
SELECT table_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_schema='mySchema' AND column_name = 'myColumnName'

Answer (score 0):

Use `TEXT` data type in your case will solve the problem. Remember to remove the SIZE. By default, TEXT data type holds up to 2^16 bytes.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html ( search TEXT )

Comment: **Out of desperation I changed the datatype to text, and still it's limited to 1000 characters.**

Comment: No. OP specified the SIZE.

Comment: Are you sure downvoting this answer is Correct ?

Comment: Dunno about the downvote, but the size being specified hasn't been mentioned by OP.

Comment: You're right, as mentioned in my answer, by default, TEXT size is much larger than 1000 characters, therefore it assumes he sets the SIZE to 1000. He probably forgets to remove / modify the size when he changes from VARCHAR to TEXT

Comment: Yes, I did try changing it to text too. As I said earlier the `DESC` shows the size has changed. However on insertion it denies taking in anything more than 1000(which is the initially set field size) characters. I am assuming it's a MySQL bug! It works fine on  different schemas though.